# Adding Object to Array with Mongoose Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a User class in Mongoose that looks like this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',{

    Email: String,
    Password: String,
    Firstname: String,
    Lastname: String,
    Address: String,
    Address_State: String, //index
    Zipcode: Number,

    Cars: [

        {

            Make: String,
            Model: String,
            Year: Number,
            Mileage: Number,
            Vin: String
        }

    ]
});
```

I have created a user object in another part of code that contains

```
var user = new User({
    Email: email,
    Firstname: firstname,
    Lastname: lastname
});
```

and I want to add the list of cars to the object.

I have tried to do

```
for(var motor in transportation.results) {

           user.Cars.push({

                           Make: motor.make,
                           Model: motor.model,
                           Year: motor.year,
                           Mileage: Number

                            });

}
```

But the result I get is

```
{
"Email":"derrick@curiousminds.com",
"Firstname":"Derrick",
"Lastname":"Franco",
"_id":"556cdfb06b98604d04d73900",
"Cars":[{"_id":"556cdfb06b98604d04d73901"}]
}
```

Is there a specific function or method to add objects to an array in a mongoose object?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the array first before adding it to the Cars array field of the new user object. Consider the following:

```
var cars = [];
for(var motor in transportation.results) {
    cars.push({
        Make: motor.make,
        Model: motor.model,
        Year: motor.year,
        Mileage: motor.mileage
    });
}

var user = new User({
    Email: email,
    Firstname: firstname,
    Lastname: lastname,
    Cars = cars
});

user.save(function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('Success!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way that I went about the loop, I had to change

```
for(var motor in transportation.results) {

           user.Cars.push({

                           Make: motor.make,
                           Model: motor.model,
                           Year: motor.year,
                           Mileage: Number

                            });

}
```

to a iterator loop in the for

```
for(var i = 0; i < transportation.results.length; i++) {

     user.Cars.push({Make: transportation.results[i].make,
                     Model: transportation.results[i].model,
                     Year: transportation.results[i].year

                     });

}//for loop
```